# Constraints not changing when user cancels searching

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a search icon as my right bar button item. When the user taps the icon, it allows the user to search and only show certain values in the tableview.  It also hides the nav bar buttons at the top and the `filterBar` just below the navigation controller

```
func setupNavBarButtons() {
    let searchImage = UIImage(named: "search_icon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSearch))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonItem
    setupFilterButton()
}
```

filter bar and navbar items to be hidden while searching like so:

```
func handleSearch() {
    searchController.searchBar.isHidden = false
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil
    filterBar.isHidden = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

And then it to reappear again once user stops searching, like so:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    setupNavBarButtons()
    searchController.searchBar.isHidden = true
    filterBar.isHidden = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    // Also tried tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Before Search:

[image]

During Search

[image]

After search: As you can see the tableview doesn't return to where it originally was.  The `filterBar` is the gray view with 'Map' and 'Location'

[image]

Still got the same issue so I've uploaded my project here:

https://github.com/lukejones1/bug

Comment: `tableView.setNeedsLayout` which will try to inform the UI engine to redraw.

Comment: When the changing of constraint constant values is done do call [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: @BharatModi called it after `tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
`.  Doesn't seem to wrok

Comment: @New16 How would I implement that?

Comment: No call `tableView.setNeedsLayout()` and then execute `view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: @New16 Not sure where i should be calling `tableView.setNeedsLayout()` but I've tried ti in multiple places and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Immediately after you set the constraints you should call this.

Comment: The height of the navigationBar is 64, try using 64 instead of 40.

Comment: @New16 Called both straight after `tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true`. Set the constant to both 64 and 104(the filterBar is 40 pixels). Still no change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125090/discussion-between-new16-and-luke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, You added 'height' layout constraint with 40 px.
and you added 'height' layout constraint with 0 px when user clicked search button.
and again, you added 'height' layout constraint with 40 px when user clicked cancel button.

You need to reuse the layout constraint.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var filterBarHeightLC : NSLayoutConstraint?

lazy var tableView : UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    tv.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    tv.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    tv.backgroundColor = .red
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tv
}()

lazy var filterBar : UIView = {
    let bar = UIView()
    bar.backgroundColor = .blue
    bar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return bar
}()

fileprivate lazy var filterButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
    button.setTitle("Filter", for: UIControlState())
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.left
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

fileprivate lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
    let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)
    sc.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    sc.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    sc.searchResultsUpdater = self
    sc.delegate = self
    sc.view.tintColor = UIColor.white
    sc.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    sc.searchBar.delegate = self
    return sc
}()

func setupNavBarButtons() {
    let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Search", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSearch))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonItem
    setupFilterButton()
}

func setupFilterButton() {
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
    containerView.addSubview(filterButton)
    filterButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    filterButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    let filterBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containerView)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = filterBarButtonItem
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupViews()
    setupNavBarButtons()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
}

func handleSearch() {
    searchController.searchBar.isHidden = false
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil

    // changed!
    filterBarHeightLC?.constant = 0
}

func setupViews() {
    view.addSubview(filterBar)
    view.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    filterBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    filterBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    filterBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 64).isActive = true

    // changed!
    filterBarHeightLC = filterBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    filterBarHeightLC?.isActive = true
}

extension ViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

func filteredContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    setupNavBarButtons()
    searchController.searchBar.isHidden = true

    // changed!
    filterBarHeightLC?.constant = 40
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
}
```

}

Have a fun coding! :)